# Can I use for_each output as for_each input in an other resource in same *.tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using 2 ARM terraform resources (*azuread_user, azurerm_role_assignment*) in one .tf file and want to have the for_each ouput var $id from azuread_user as for_each input var for azurerm_role_assignment principal_id. Is there a way to do this? Can you provide a code example?

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "init" {}

locals {

  csv_data = file("${path.module}/users.csv")
  instances = csvdecode(local.csv_data)

}

resource "azuread_user" "init" {

  for_each = { for inst in local.instances : inst.display_name => inst }

  display_name = each.value.display_name
  mail_nickname = each.value.mail_nickname
  user_principal_name = each.value.user_principal_name
  password            = "XXX#XXX#XXX"
  force_password_change = "true"
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ard" {
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.init.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = "HERE THE FOR_EACH INPUT FROM OUTPUT VAR $ID"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-to-one correspondence between `azurerm_role_assignment.ard` instances and `azuread_user.init` instances, you can use `azuread_user.init` directly as the `for_each` repetition expression on `azurerm_role_assignment.ard`:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ard" {
  for_each = azuread_user.init

  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.init.id
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = each.value.id
}
```

The above can work because any resource that has `for_each` set appears in Terraform language expressions as a map from the instance keys to objects representing each instance. That matches the requirements for resource `for_each` and ensures that `each.value` will be an object produced by one `azuread_user.init` instance, correlated by the map keys.

If you had a entry in your CSV with the display name "MABU" then you'd see instances with the following addresses in the plan:

- `azuread_user.init["MABU"]`
- `azurerm_role_assignment.ard["MABU"]`

Answer (score 0):

**NOT TESTED:**

the azuread_user will output an attribute call id.

You can use count and count.index to loop through the iteration of the value.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ard" {
  scope                = "${data.azurerm_subscription.init.id}"
  count                = "${length(azuread_user.init)}" 
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = "${element(azuread_user.init.*.id, count.index)}"
}
```